# Problem in rendering asp.net Menu control in Firefox and IE

Tags: asp.net, object, menu

I am new to asp.net. The web site I'm working on has a master page. I defined a asp menu in the master page. When I render the page in browser (both ie and firefox), half the time everything works fine. Menu gets displayed fine, submenu item are visible when I hover my mouse over the Menu item.

But rest half of the time, things get bad. Instead of the arrow sign next to main menu (which signifies the menu has got sub items), I get "Expand item" sign. When I hover over the item, in IE it shows "**Object Expected**" error. In firefox, I get "**Menu_HoverStatic**" and "**Menu_Unhover**" not defined error.

I googled it and discovered several people have faced the same issue. I tried various workaround but nothing seems to be working.

I think the issue is related to webresources.axd file. I went over the source of the Html page rendered and it contained link to javascript file by the name webresource.axd. When I tried to open the link mentioned, the browser showed the error that "page not there".

I have created proper extension mapping for webresource file in IIS. I have even unchecked the option to verify the file.

I have already wasted almost half my day over it. I hope somebody could help me out. I am using IIS7, visual studio 2008 on Win 7 box.

Comment: Why don't you post what you found as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is generally related to problems with *.axd files and how they are processed in IIS - which is why it often happens on a production server and not on dev.

In IIS6, make sure that the "Verify that file exists" checkbox is unchecked for *.axd in the application extension area. In IIS7 this has changed to the rather more obvious "Invoke handler only if request is mapped to file" for *.axd files under Handler mapppings.

Another option is to run "aspnet_regiis -ir -enable" in order to register your *.axd files for the latest version of .net